# C++ store Class template objects with different specialization inside unique std collection

Tags: c++, templates, stl, variadic-templates, c++17

I have an Action class specialized through templates. I would like to store different specialization of Action types inside an unique std c++ collection (std::map, std::vector, etc...).

Here the Action classes:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <utility>

template<typename T, typename... Args>
class Action {
private:
    std::function<T(Args...)> function;
public:

    explicit Action(std::function<T(Args...)> function) : function(std::move(function)) {};

    T execute(Args... args) {
        return function(args...);
    };
};

template<typename... Args>
class Action<void, Args...> {
private:
    std::function<void(Args...)> function;
public:

    explicit Action(std::function<void(Args...)> function) : function(std::move(function)) {};

    void execute(Args... args) {
        function(args...);
    };
};

template<>
class Action<void> {
private:
    std::function<void()> function;
public:

    explicit Action(std::function<void()> function) : function(std::move(function)) {};

    void execute() {
        function();
    };
};
```

Here there is a live [example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/AlmJ3SSCbfERIm5A).

The problem is that I cannot do

```
auto action1 = Action<void>([](){std::cout << "hello world!" << std::endl;});
auto action2 = Action<void, std::string>([](std::string text){std::cout << text << std::endl;});
auto action3 = Action<void>([](){std::cout << "bluff" << std::endl;});
auto action4 = Action<int, int, int>([](int a, int b){return a + b;});

std::vector<Action> actions = {action1, action2, action3, action4};
```

because Action template specialization is missing in vector declaration. The way to create an empty class interface implemented by all Action classes

```
class ActionI {};

...

std::vector<ActionI> newActions = {action1, action2, action3, action4};
```

doesn't work because when I loop on **newActions** vector I am not able to cast single action to the correct specialization. Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: The whole design is wrong, vector is homogeneous container. And your specializations are redundant.

Comment: What would you even do with the actions - they all potentially take different arguments and return different things?

Comment: @liliscent I would like to build a small GUI library; so the idea was that the Action is passed to a Component and then stored there in a std::vector. Then, when an event occurs on the Component the Action is executed. If possible, I don't want to propagate template parameters on Component classes. So if you believe the design is wrong, what would you suggest? What I would like to have is a std::function or a lambda or something similar (as generic as possible) to push and store inside a GUI component without using templates.

Comment: @Barry I'm trying to create a generic Action class that can wrap a lambda function. The idea was to pass this Action to a GUI Component (for example a Button) with a method, and then to store Actions inside Component in a std::vector. When an event on that component occurs one of the Action present in the vector can be executed. Since I'm making this minimal GUI library, I'm not able to know which type of function will be passed. So, yes, potentially should be as generic as possible; I would like to avoid to propagate template parameters to GUI components too, if possible..

Comment: @Squerut Ignoring a return value can be done easily, but what arguments do you pass to the function then?